# NSDateComponents possible timezone bug?

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponents, nstimezone

Wonder if I've found a bug with NSDateComponents.

When using NSDateComponents to calculate dates and switching between time zones, it's possible to get the wrong date on the simulator (not tested on device).

It seems that it's the right offset, but going in the wrong direction. Either that, or I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something (which is always a distinct possibility).

**Sample:**

*Set the system time to a time zone other than UTC (mine was Mexico, UTC-05:00)*

```
// Get the components for the current absolute time.
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Get the calendar, which seems to set the time zone to the current time zone
components.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
// Set the time zone to UTC
components.calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

// Log the date
NSLog(@"Date at time zone: %@ : %@", components.calendar.timeZone, [components date]);
// Outputs (e.g): "Date at time zone: GMT (GMT) offset 0 : 2013-06-21 14:55:56 +0000"
// This should be absolute time, so any changes in the time zone should offset
// relative to this.

// Set the time zone to the local time zone (e.g. Mexico, 5 hours behind)
components.calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
// Log the date
NSLog(@"Date at time zone: %@ : %@", components.calendar.timeZone, [components date]);
// Outputs (e.g.): "Date at time zone: Local Time Zone (America/Mexico_City (CDT) offset -18000 (Daylight)) :2013-06-21 19:55:56 +0000"
```

Assuming Mexico, shouldn't the second date be five hours behind the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have set `components.calendar.timeZone` to the Mexican time zone, `components`
represents (in your example)

```
2013-06-21 14:55:56 in the Mexican time zone
```

therefore `[components date]` returns an `NSDate` for that point in time.

The `NSLog` output uses the `description` method of `NSDate`, and that prints the point in
time always in the GMT time zone, which is

```
2013-06-21 19:55:56 +0000
```

So everything looks OK to me.

Comment: Understood. Was assuming that the date passed to components was immutable but `[components date];` is actually returning a _new_ absolute point in time depending on the time zone.  

Makes sense now. Thanks very much.

Comment: @SimonFairbairn: You are welcome. (Time zone and calendar related calculations can be confusing!)